# Elasticsearch index short words + make indexes applying EdgeNGram

Tags: search, elasticsearch, search-engine

I am using Elasticsearch with a EdgeNGram filter which is set as follows:

```
"edgeNGram": {
    "type": "edgeNGram",
    "min_gram": 3,
    "max_gram": 15,
},
```

The problem is that when I make a query using very short words, they are completely omitted from the search. Let's say I type in "Vitamin C" -> this gives me results for the first term "Vitamin" only. Is there any way how to tell Elasticsearch not to use EdgeNGram filter when indexing words up to 3 characters?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

These are my settings:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_SETTINGS = {
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "sk_hunspell": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "sk_lowercase", "sk_SK", "stopwords_SK",
                        "edgeNGram", "asciifolding",
                        "remove_duplicities",
                    ]
                },
            },
            "filter": {
                "sk_SK": {
                    "type": "hunspell",
                    "locale": "sk_SK",
                    "dedup": True,
                    "recursion_level": 0,
                    "ignore_case": True,
                },
                "sk_lowercase": {
                    "type": "lowercase",
                },
                "stopwords_SK": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": STOPWORDS_SK,
                },
                "remove_duplicities": {
                    "type": "unique",
                    "only_on_same_position": True
                },
                "edgeNGram": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 15,
                    "token_chars": ["letter", "digit"],
                },
            },
        }
    }
}
```

In the database I store information about vitamins, minerals and medicinal plants. (Their use, collecting, blooming, health benefits etc.) The information are written in Slovak. (The names of the plants and minerals are also stored in Czech and Latin).

Comment: no, it's not possible to switch filter based on a search term size. However you could treat "Vitamin C" as a single word - i.e. don't treat spaces as separators. Can you add more information about your data and how you're doing searches? Possibly EdgeNGram isn't right for your use case?

Comment: I have updated my post, thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

This idea may be a hack but you could pad words less than 3 with a special charecter before inserting them into the index so they are length 3.

When you accept the user's query you would have to also pad their words less than three with the same special charecter.

You would need to create a custom tokenizer for this.